# In the VS Code "Debug Console", run a JavaScript await function

Tags: javascript, debugging, asynchronous, promise, visual-studio-code

In the VS Code "Debug Console", I can evaluate expressions on my code in the middle of a debugging session when debugging my JavaScript code, including running my functions. However, I seem to be unable to run `async` functions, even when I use an IIFE, etc.

I have the following code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getUrl() {
  const response = await axios.get('http://example.com/');
  return response.data;
}

async function main() {
  const response = await getUrl();
  console.log(response);
}

main();
```

I set a breakpoint on the `async function main() {` line, then I run the VS Code Debugger. I then try to run the `getUrl` function in different ways in the Debug Console, such as `getUrl()`, `getUrl().then((data) => data)`, and `(async () => getUrl())()`, which all return `Promise { pending }`). `main()` returns the same (if run after the function's definition). None of these methods print the function's return value.

I also tried `await getUrl()`, which returns `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

I know I can output the functions I want, within the code with `console.log`, if really necessary, but I'm looking for a solution that specifically uses the Debug Console to print the results of promises specifically created with an `await` function.

Therefore, is there really any way to output the results of a function in the VS Code Debug Console, when the function is `async`?

Comment: Yes, of course all of those return a promise. However, calling `main()` *should* print the result

Comment: Have you tried `await getUrl()`? Not sure whethr VS Code supports that already - node does with a command line flag.

Comment: `getUrl().then(data => { /*set breakpoint here */ })`

Comment: @Bergi Actually `main()` returns `Promise { pending }` too. And I already tried `await getUrl()`.

Comment: Are you running those while you are halted on the breakpoint? If not, calling `main` should definitely log the result (unless it gets rejected).

Comment: @JonasW. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require modifying the code. If I really wanted to, then yep, I could just write code that prints what I want. But ideally it would be possible to get what I want from the debug console.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, I'm running these while on the breakpoint. The debug console can't be used outside of a debug session. If you're talking about calling `main()` from the code, then yep, it does work on the last line of the code I posted. But it would be nice to be able to debug async functions from the debug console. Otherwise, as a last resort, it's definitely possible to just write `console.log` where necessary.

Comment: No, you cannot do asynchronous things while being halted - the event loop needs to spin to receive the ajax result (and any other promise). Try continuing the debugger, it should eventually log the result.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use the debug console but a real repl. I'm sure there's one for JS in VS Code.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll check out some alternative solutions, then.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38316 ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

VS Code Debug Console supports top level async/await (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#top-level-await) however the issue might be you're paused on the breakpoint.

> if you use await while paused on a breakpoint, you'll only get a pending Promise back. This is because the JavaScript event loop is paused while on a breakpoint.

Comment: So... can we just not get anything in the debugger?

Comment: Or, I should ask, is there a way to unpause the event loop in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I was wondering why the same promise is being resolved in node's REPL interpreter but not in debug console, so which means I have to resume the application from breakpoint an then try to run the awaiting code to get the resolved promises asap in debug console

Comment: A request to enable this is marked as wontfix upstream in [833928 - DevTools: console's await doesn't work when debugger is paused - chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833928#c10): *"There is no workaround for this, and no plans to work on this. The issue here is that running a microtask queue during a debug break heavily violates regular behavior of the web page. When you await a promise, the expectation is that the handler runs after the script has completed and you'd run the microtask queue. At a breakpoint this is not going to happen."*

Answer (score 13):

@jonas-wilms has the right idea in a comment on the original question.

@andrej-k has a great point to the fact that the event loop is paused.

Putting those together, here is how you get the output from an `async` function when paused at a breakpoint in the VS Code Debug Console:

```
// config.entry() is an async function

config.entry().then((result) => { debugger; })
```

### `config.entry` is an async function

[image: config.entry is an async function]

### Call function with `.then()` that has `debugger;`

[image: Call function with .then() that has debugger;]

### Dump `result` in the `.then()` callback

[image: Dump result in the .then() callback]